# Can I train new grapevines to be vertical, sturdy and self supporting?

Tags: grape-vine, trellis

I have 3 new vines, trellissed up in a makeshift, admittedly low-quality, trellis system. I could do a better job with it but my time is better spent elsewhere at the moment. I had these three grapes given to me to plant, so I threw something together.

I have a small yard and there's no ideal spot, but at least this area is South-facing.

There are and will be more raspberries planted, to take over and control weeds and maybe a tile pathway (I'm removing soil to lower the level), but there are three grapes.

Since I don't have the best system and I know the weight in the future will pull down the wire, I was wondering if there was such a system where people can make the great trunks thick and self-supporting almost like miniature trees. I don't mind if it takes several years to get there. That would be the easiest and cleanest for this area.

[image: wide view of patch of grapes and raspberries]

[image: close up new grape vine against pole]

More immediately, what should I be doing now, in early August, in terms of pruning and training, and how much can I prune or cut healthy vine growth with benefit? It grows vigorously and I was planning to let the 'limbs' grow as much as they please, with moderate training of the limbs and heavy training of the trunk, knowing that I will prune, and probably aggressively, in the fall. I was wondering though, should I prune now and would that direct more growth to the trunk, or would that waste it's overall energy, or would it make no difference to the trunk whatsoever?

Comment: I think this goes by names like 'bush trained' or 'goblet trained' vines, as [here](https://www.winescholarguild.org/blog/vine-school-part-1-common-vine-training-systems#:~:text=HEAD%2DTRAINED%20(BUSH%2DVINE)) and I see advice on training it places like [here](https://lodigrowers.com/optimizing-head-trained-vineyards/) but I have no first hand experience.  Really interesting idea!

Answer (score 2):

1. Grapevines produce on their horizontal branches.

[image: Horizontal vines make for big harvests]

2. Trunks will eventually support themselves, but for sturdier growth, they need limbs along their length, not bareness.
3. These points tell you why vineyards train two-tier candelabras. They look like decorative [**espaliers**](https://www.myefco.com/int/green-ideas/come-realizzare-un-vigneto-spalliera/), but produce best that way.

[image: Espalier grapes]

4. Raspberries sucker so readily, you will not reach the grapes for their thorns, unless you grow that rare thornless variety.

Answer (score 0):

The trunk is unlikely to be a problem . But each year very long , branches will grow which need support. They will grow over your roof, not easy to harvest.

Comment: Do you know how high of a self supporting trunk can be grown?  What will happen to unsupported grape vines?

Comment: I expect that unsupported ,they will lay on the ground unless they reach something to climb.